# Is type hinting helping the performance of PHP scripts?

Tags: php, performance, type-hinting

Type hinting helps the compiler to assume the type of the variable, but, as the PHP is a dynamic scripting interpreted language, the question came to my mind if it's possible that type hinting even makes the runtime faster or not?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP is a dynamic language.
Dynamic languages only support runtime checking.
Type hinting is runtime type checking.
Runtime type checking is bad for performance.
Therefore, type hinting is bad for performance.

Comment: +1 - I like this, it's almost like a zen of type-hinting (or something) :)

Comment: What about running Zend Optimizer or something similar with caches the opcode?

Comment: what does ff 9's type inference, how does that help improve performance? http://www.extremetech.com/computing/94532-firefox-9-javascript-performance-improved-by-20-30-with-type-inference

Comment: @Ming-Tang Are there any bench-marks to back your answer?

Comment: It does affect performance, but the hit is negligible in most real-world applications. The benefits (safer code) outweigh the cost. Please note that a future version of PHP might come with a [JIT compiler](http://news.php.net/php.internals/95531), which may take advantage of type hinting to compile to a more optimized, and therefore faster, code.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Most languages are dynamic these days. That is completely irrelevant however.


All compiled languages *can* benefit a lot from type hinting. Type hinting makes it much easier to compile to optimized bytecode during the compile phase. Even if PHP was *interpreted* in 2010, type hinting could be used by the interpreter to make optimizations - and it is impossible to conclude that type hinting is bad for performance or that it at some point was bad for performance.

Comment: For the record, I added a benchmark, and no, the interpreted does not optimize its job with type hinting (PHP 7.4). Type hinting adds extra validation and it requires a little more work.  So this answer is still valid.

Comment: @frodeborli: type hinting causes about 35–70 % overhead over plain function call in PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73812702/334451 for details. As long as PHP type hinting is implemented as mandatory checking during runtime (as opposed to compile time), type hinting will always reduce the performance. As for the "compile to optimized bytecode" argument, PHP could use tracing JIT without any hints so explicit markup in the source code is *debugging aid*, not a performance tool Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support disabling runtime type hint checking similar to disabling `assert()`.

Comment: This answer is wrong on an important technicality (see my answer). The 3rd point is basically wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Type hinting only hinders performance because it requires (for objects) to test the inheritance hierarchy. To make things worse, this kind of check is expensive in PHP because it is done in time proportional to the depth of the hierarchy.

A test for type, such the one done for the `array` hint is a much smaller overhead, though.

Furthermore, it is currently not used for any optimization purposes.

It is however, a useful defensive programming feature.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer and the other answers as well as the original question are wrong on an important aspect / technicality:

```php
/**
 * @param string|null $input          <--- this is a type hint
 */
function test($input): string         <--- this is a type declaration
{
    return $input;
}
```

- **type hinting** is an IDE feature (built on top of language functionality such as types, typed declarations, meta constructs, xDoc etc)

  - it is intended for development-time, typically for documentation and (before attributes) for metaprogramming
  - as such, the performance hit at run-time is probably negligible (if all you have is a bunch of PHPDocs) and the IDE, depending on implementation, might actually get faster (e.g. hinting small specific types instead of god objects as is typical in a javascript environment)
  - unless you're doing some sort of meta programming (doing stuff with PHPDoc), (bad) type hinting should not cause any compile-time or run-time problems
- **type declarations** are a language feature

  - it is intended for the application run-time
  - bad/wrong type declarations *will* cause compile-time or run-time errors
  - some type declarations *will* (negligibly) slow down the application:

    ```php
    function test(): SomeClass {
        return $x;  // $x can only be checked at run-time
    }
    ```
  - some type declarations are actually checked at compile-time and incur no additional performance hits (although in this case, the previous point still applies):

    ```php
    interface IParent {
        public function test(): SomeClass;
    }
    interface IChild extends IParent {
        public function test(): SomeUnrelatedClass; // 
    }
    ```

As others have said, the benefits of types far outweigh the disadvantages and *eventually* there may be a point where a stricter typing regime would actually improve performance (by offloading all type checks to compile time and optimising flow based on types).

---

TL;DR Bottom line: **No, type hinting does not make the runtime any slower.**

Answer (score 2):

I did a benchmark

https://github.com/EFTEC/php-benchmarks#type-hinting   (you can check the whole code, test it and check it by yourself).

```php
/**
 * @param DummyClass $arg1
 * @param DummyClass $arg2
 *
 * @return DummyClass
 */
function php5($arg1,$arg2){
    return new DummyClass();
}
function php7(DummyClass $arg1,DummyClass $arg2): DummyClass {
    return new DummyClass();
}
```

- php5  0.0006339550018310547 seconds
- php7  0.0007991790771484375 seconds

And type hinting is around 10% slower than without type hinting.  **It is not considerably slow unless** it is required in a vital part of the code (a huge loop for example) or we need raw performance.

I prefer PHPdoc, it works similar, it's more complete and it doesn't affect the performance.

Comment: Can you extend test on PHP 8?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73812702/334451 for an example that uses less expensive test function and the overhead is about 35–70 % already. PHP performance for creating new objects is pretty bad so if you test that, the overhead of the function call signature will dimish.

Answer (score 1):

All type hinting in PHP does is add code that tests the type of the parameters and fails if its not what's expected, so type hinting NEVER helps performance. Its only real use is for debugging, so if you have a function that's called very often, removing the type hint in the production code can speed things up, especially since checking the type of an object isn't the fastest thing in the world.

also see [when should I use type hinting in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/when-should-i-use-type-hinting-in-php)

Comment: Accurate except for "Its only real use is for debugging".  Type hinting introduces a level of safety to your code.

Comment: Second link is dead