# What is the performance overhead of type-hinting in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, type-hinting

How significant is the performance overhead of type-hinting in PHP - is it significant enough to be a consideration in the decision to use it or not?

Comment: No. It is not. Seriously. You'll lose much more time fixing a bug which didn't get caught because you didn't use type hinting than type hinting will ever accrue in runtime. Benchmark it if you really want to know.

Comment: Type hinting will only make your code more organize. Do not hesitate to use it. Don't waste time benchmarking it.

Comment: Virtually no difference on average: http://3v4l.org/lWgY6/perf#tabs, http://3v4l.org/110SL/perf#tabs

Comment: @deceze Interesting that it looks like a 10% improvement in HHVM. I guess it actually uses typehints to optimize?

Comment: "Seriously. You'll lose much more time fixing a bug which didn't get caught ... than ... runtime." Umm, except that the dev's debugging time is not interchangeable with the *user's* run-time. "Benchmark it if you really want to know." -- Now you're (were :) ) talking. BTW, [here's some fresh data](https://gist.github.com/dstogov/b9fc0fdccfb8bf7bae121ce3d3ff1db1#file-typed_ref_prperties_bench-php) for the new "typed properties" feature (sch'ed for 7.4). The slowdown here is 2-3% avg. Not significant, but not completely negligible either.

Comment: "Don't waste time benchmarking it." This is a sad, recurring meme all over the PHP community, and especially on SO, that "performance", no matter the context, is first and foremost a *curse word*... Young programmers, readers of SO, please don't fall to this fallacious dogmatism! **Do benchmark, when in doubt!** (Hint: how do you think all those crappy, sluggish, bloated, careless, annoying sites that infest the web are made: with due attention/willingness to measure things, or by repeating this mantra & dismissing the cost of every single aspect that only ("presumably") adds 1%?...)

Comment: @Sz.: "Not significant, but not completely negligible either" - here you answered the question. The question was if the overhead was "significant", not if it was "completely negligible". Your comments are not helpful! Accusing people of dogmatism is not nice and completely unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not significant. If you need to do something algorithmically intensive, like sound-processing or 3D-programming, you should use another programming language.

if you want hard data, make a benchmark...

```
<?php

function with_typehint(array $bla)
{
    if(count($bla) > 55) {
        die("Array to big");
    }
}

function dont_typehint($bla)
{
    if(count($bla) > 55) {
        die("Array to big");
    }   
}

function benchmark($fn)
{
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $array = array("bla", 3);
    for($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
        $fn($array);
    }
    $end = microtime(TRUE);
    return $end-$start;
}

printf("with typehint: %.3fs\n", benchmark("with_typehint"));
printf("dont typehint: %.3fs\n", benchmark("dont_typehint"));
```

on my computer, the performance is the same. sometimes its faster with, sometimes without typehinting:

```
$ php Documents/type_hinting.php 
with typehint: 0.432s
dont typehint: 0.428s

$ php Documents/type_hinting.php 
with typehint: 0.414s
dont typehint: 0.416s
```

Comment: What about a more realistic scenario involving class hierarchies in separate files (perhaps even namespaced/autoloaded)?

Comment: my example is unrealistic in that it overestimates the influence of type-hinting. in my example, there is 1) type-hinting, 2) a function call (with_typehint), 3) another function call (count), 4) a comparison, 5) an "implicit" return statement. so 20% of my code is influenced by type-hinting. in a realistic example, less than 1% of the time spent will be at a place where type-hinting takes place, therefore reducing the difference even more. tl;dr: if you cannot measure a time difference with my example, you will not measure a time difference with any realistic example either.

Comment: @Alastair if you are unsure, just write another test. but IMHO this is wasted time.

Comment: "if you want hard data, make a benchmark..." That is, actually, the only acceptable part of the answer, Mike. Had your test been made reliable, that would have been a fine bit, too, but the very fact that it was so unstable means it's unfortunately useless. Yet, you went on to conclude the results were "the same"... ;)

(Note: I'm *by no means* implying it's a significant overhead, obviously. I'm just fighting the trend where dogmatism is used to replace "hard data".)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer by creating a simple bechmark, for example:

```
$test1 = function(stdClass $obj){};
$test2 = function($obj){};

$begin = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $test1(new stdClass);
}
$end = microtime(true);

$timeElapsedTest1 = $end - $begin;

$begin = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $test2(new stdClass);
}
$end = microtime(true);

$timeElapsedTest2 = $end - $begin;

echo 'difference: ', $timeElapsedTest1 - $timeElapsedTest2;
```

Differences for 1 000 000 loops on my computer:

```
1.  0.0994789600372 ms 
2.  0.0944871902466 ms 
3.  0.103265047073 ms 
4.  0.0899112224579 ms 
5.  0.0860922336578 ms 
6.  0.0973558425903 ms 
7.  0.0905900001526 ms 
8.  0.0891189575195 ms 
9.  0.09983086586 ms 
10. 0.0914621353149 ms
```

After I replaced `stdClass` with `array`, differences for 1 000 000 loops on my computer changed a  bit:

```
1.  0.00209307670593 ms 
2.  0.00217390060425 ms 
3.  0.00558805465698 ms 
4.  0.00264406204224 ms 
5.  0.00367116928101 ms 
6.  0.00262594223022 ms 
7.  0.00353169441223 ms 
8.  0.00217604637146 ms 
9.  0.00049090385437 ms 
10. 0.002516746521 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function you're calling is really short, the overhead seems to be typically between 35–70 %. Example case of this would be simple getters called from inner loop. As long as PHP doesn't have INI setting that avoids this overhead, I'd avoid using type hinting for functions or methods called from inner loop if you have any performance targets. I created test script at https://3v4l.org/hOVBp and here are the results for selected PHP versions:

**Output for 8.1.10**
unhinted: Elapsed 0.20 seconds
hinted: Elapsed 0.29 seconds
Type hinting causes **47 % overhead** for small functions.

**Output for 8.0.23**
unhinted: Elapsed 0.21 seconds
hinted: Elapsed 0.35 seconds
Type hinting causes **66 % overhead** for small functions.

**Output for 7.4.30**
unhinted: Elapsed 0.26 seconds
hinted: Elapsed 0.42 seconds
Type hinting causes **65 % overhead** for small functions.

Here's the test script I used above:

```
<?php

function hinted(array $a, StdClass $b): int
{
 return count($a);
}

function unhinted($a, $b)
{
  return count($a);
}

$max = 10000000;
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = new StdClass();
$b->foo = "bar";

// run unhinted test first to cause any possible cold startup effects to hit it more to make this as fair as possible for hinted code
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
  $rv = unhinted($a, $b);
$elapsed_unhinted = microtime(true) - $start;
printf("unhinted: Elapsed %.2f seconds\n", $elapsed_unhinted);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
  $rv = hinted($a, $b);
$elapsed_hinted = microtime(true) - $start;
printf("hinted: Elapsed %.2f seconds\n", $elapsed_hinted);

if ($elapsed_unhinted > 0)
{
  $overhead = $elapsed_hinted / $elapsed_unhinted;
  if ($overhead <= 1.0)
    printf("No overhead for hinted signature, factor=%.2\n", $overhead);
  else
    printf("Type hinting causes %d %% overhead for small functions.\n", round(100*($overhead - 1.0)));
}
```

Comment: However, note that if you inline the code (`$rv = count($a);`) instead of calling even the unhinted version, you get about 4x the performance of calling the hinted function. PHP has pretty high function call overhead in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure these benchmarks tell the correct picture. When I made a benchmark using class methods and enabled JIT (which is enabled by default), there seem to a microscopic difference. The difference may be larger for class type hints than for primitive types. I suspect JIT will benefit more in coming PHP versions from type hints, so I don't think this is good advice.

Comment: Yes, the overhead is about twice the function call alone (that is, if the function body were empty, having type hints doubles the CPU time needed to call that empty function). If the function body is expensive to run, obviously the overhead of function call will be relatively minor issue. In many cases the overhead is acceptable but you still should understand that *type hinting in PHP will cause runtime overhead*. Unless you're calling the function in tight inner loop, the overhead is not meaningful in practice.