# in php5 what is the technical term for specifying class name before object variable in a function parameters

Tags: php

`function(myCar $cars)`

What is the technical term of myCars?

`catch(Exception $e)`

I know what is the try, catch block and exception term. But I want the technical name for representing a class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called Type Hinting. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php.

Comment: one more think i want, what is the use case of type hint

Comment: Because it allows PHP to help check that you're passing the correct types into your functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/when-should-i-use-type-hinting-in-php

Comment: also in the case of catch blocks it allows you to have different catch blocks for different types of exceptions