# PHP - To Type Hint or not To Type Hint

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(When) should I use type hinting in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/when-should-i-use-type-hinting-in-php)

When programming in PHP should one strive to type hint wherever possible, or just accept and embrace that PHP is a loosely typed language?

Comment: I encourage to use type hints *whenever possible*! It makes your application much more solid. Unfortunately it doesn't work with the internal types.

Answer (score 0):

Type hinting will give you more help from the IDE, which is nice.

If a function will/may crash not given a proper object you may as well type hint, to catch errors early and have more self documentation code.